# What is the expected conversion time from AWS snapshot to volume?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I converted a snapshot with a capacity of 1TB to a volume, and it took about 1 second.
Am I correct in my understanding that restoring from a snapshot takes almost no time?

I think it will take more time.
Is this normal and does it always work at this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume is created so quickly because it is really an "uninitialized" volume with links over to the snapshot data. The snapshot data is actually stored behind the scenes in an S3 bucket (a bucket hidden from you, not a bucket in your AWS account). As you use the new volume, the first time a specific data block on the volume is accessed it will be pulled down from S3. This means the first time you access any data on the volume it will be relatively slow.

There are methods to "initialize" the newly created volume to basically pull down all the data from the snapshot before you use it, so that the first time you try to read any data it will be fast. You can read more about that in [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html).